# Google sdk not registering

Tags: ios, google-plus

I was using google sdk 1.7.0

when I now click the google sign in button, it says i need to update to google sdk 1.7.1

I did that.. and followed all the instructions, unfortunately it still says i need to update to google sdk 1.7.1

```
2014-10-05 18:44:42.916 MyApp[54006:120f] You are using Google+ iOS SDK version 1.7.0
2014-10-05 18:44:42.916 MyApp[54006:120f] Get the new version 1.7.1 at https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started
```

what else do i need to do ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deleting the old sdk from my computer helped